# Running a JMeter script with nohup

Tags: bash, shell, jmeter, nohup

For the first time I'm just playing around with `nohup` on top of an Ubuntu server. I read few docs about `nohup` and got to know about the running commands with options such as `nohup ./server.sh &`.

What I want to know is that, how should I be running the `JMeter` script (in headless mode) using `nohup`? Following is the script I needed to run with `nohup`:

`./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/chamith/WSO2MB/new/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/GamesSubscriber.jmx`

When I tried using the normal `nohup` operation within the script it always throws me an error saying `-n command not found`. How should I move on with this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Although I cannot reproduce your issue you can try surrounding your command with quotation marks like:

```
nohup "./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/chamith/WSO2MB/new/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/GamesSubscriber.jmx"
```

Also don't forget `-l` key to save the results into a file.

The full command which runs script totally in the background will look like:

```
nohup "./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/chamith/WSO2MB/new/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/GamesSubscriber.jmx -l result.jtl" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

References:

- [nohup man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)
- [nohup Execute Commands After You Exit From a Shell Prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
- [Full list of JMeter command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Comment: for me, this worked (no double quotes)
nohup ./jmeter.sh -n -t portals-engprod.jmx -l result.jtl > /home/ubuntu/jmeter/bin/jmeter.out &

Comment: If I have few parameters to pass, will it work inside the quotes ?  tried with 
nohup "./jmeter.sh -n -t Portal-1HR.jmx -R 198.162.2.3:1099 -GTest_Name=LoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=Executer -Gtest_Id=1HR_Test04" &

gives me error:
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command './jmeter.sh -n -t Portal-1HR.jmx -R 198.162.2.3:1099 -GTest_Name=LoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=Executer -Gtest_Id=1HR_Test04: No such file or directory