# Make JMeter run in background

Tags: jmeter

How to make JMeter (running remotely from another machine) run in background so that when I turn off my PC (and thus kill the putty shell), it will still continue running?

Answer (score 5):

Use below command to run Jmeter in the background:

```
nohup ./jmeter.sh -n -t test.jmx &
```

when you run above command a file nohup.out will be created in the same folder and it will store the console output.

Answer (score 2):

You can run in background without a master, this is one of the reasons I [wondered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627504/jmeter-benefits-of-master-slaves-configuration-over-all-masters-when-doing-a-l) if to choose master-slave configuration.

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t "mytest.jmx" &
```

As @Arbaz Alam mention you can use nohup, see [jmeter nohup answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254495/running-a-jmeter-script-with-nohup).

```
nohup "./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/chamith/WSO2MB/new/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/GamesSubscriber.jmx -l result.jtl" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You can check a [mailing-list answer](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-jmeter-user/200808.mbox/%3CEEA4E49D20D47B468D3E6E85147E07A404CE7F77@wms4.litle.com%3E):

```
ssh $jmeterserverone \"setsid
/home/chuesgen/jakarta-jmeter/bin/jmeter-server >> ~/jmeterServer.out
2>&1 &\"
```

Comment: Would this work with -R ip:port ip:port ..... distributed Cluster Configuration?